# Angular 5 EventSource not sending session cookie

Tags: angular, eventsource

I'm using EventSource in an Angular 5 application to get some real-time logs from the server and it was working perfectly until we added session management in the backend. Since then, all the calls done with HttpClient work fine but I see that the EventSource one doesn't send the session cookie. I read a while ago that EventSource can't handle headers but, despite this, we still decided to use it because we thought that we can send an authorization token as a parameter in the call. However, my boss changed his mind and we're not using auth tokens in the app, but session cookies instead.

Is there any way to send the cookie with EventSource or will we have to change to something more powerful, like SocketIO?

Thanks for any suggestion,

Comment: Have you tried using withCredentials when creating the source ? Probably something like: new EventSource('url', { withCredentials: true });

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by Adrian has worked perfectly. I created the EventSource adding a second parameter with `withCredentials: true` and the application can get the logs again as before.